# jQuery UI datepicker and validate: skip validation and accept null or 0000-00-00 ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, datepicker

I'm using a premade system/form that uses jquery ui Validate and Datepicker for date type fields.

I need to exclude from one page only the validation step: so I need to have the datepicker appearing for the class='date' field, but allowing to pass an empty field or in alternative a default 0000-00-00

Is there any way to do it? I'm trying but after a few hours of searching I cannot find a solution....

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried with setDefaults, or defaultdate to '' or null or '0000-00-00', nothing... And what I need is to disable the validate only on specific date fields and not others on the same form. It sounds to me something that should be easy to do, but I can't figure out how.